# Has anyone pierced darkseid's skin?

Tags: dc

I've never seen anyone really do damage to darkseid other than to his eyes. Is his skin *really* that indestructable or has it been damaged before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Darkseid, although being one of the most powerful comic book character, does have certain weaknesses.

Three of the following instances show that attacks on Darkseid have damaged him (by breaking through his skin)

### 1. Aquaman in Justice League vol 2, # 6

The Trident of Neptune is known to penetrate/pierce through almost all known objects. In *Justice League vol 2 #6*, Aquaman strikes Darkseid twice, once in his left eye and second one through his chest.

[image]
 <sub>*Justice League vol 2 # 6; click image to enlarge*</sub>

We cannot actually see the trident breaking through Darkseid's skin, so this one might not actually count.

---

### 2. The Flash in Justice League: Darkseid War

In the New 52 *Justice League: Darkseid War Chapter 4* the Anit-Monitor fuses the entity of Death with the Flash to create the Black Racer.

The Black Racer blasts his way through Darkseid's stomach and kills him.

[image] [image]
 <sub>*Justice League: Darkseid War Chapter 4; click image to enlarge*</sub>

---

### 3. Batman in Final Crisis

Of course, an answer to every question such as this, would definitely have Batman as an answer.

In *Final Crisis # 6*, Batman discovers Darkseid's one weakness: an element named **Radion**. He then makes a bullet with Radion in it and shoots Darkseid through his chest.

[image]
 <sub>*Final Crisis # 6; click image to enlarge*</sub>